# Practical limit to number of pthreads rwlocks?

Tags: pthreads, rwlock

I am writing an application that requires that certain activities for a given user are not stomped on by possibly competing threads. My entire user database is in memory and I was thinking of adding a `pthread_rwlock_t` to the user data structure. I do not anticipate more than about 10 to 20 thousand users. At 56 bytes for the lock structure that's not a lot of RAM at all. My question is, is there a practical limitation to the number of actual rwlocks you can have in a process? Please note I am NOT talking about the number of threads that can get a lock, or the number of times a given thread can increment the lock counter. Rather, I am wondering if there is some underlying kernel or other resource that backs each individual lock that I may end up exhausting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a quality-of-implementation issue: POSIX allows the initialisation of a rwlock to fail due to resource exhaustion.  However, common Linux implementations, for example, don't require any per-lock resources other than the memory for the `pthread_rwlock_t` itself.

Comment: "common Linux implementations, for example, don't require any per-lock resources other than the memory for the pthread_rwlock_t itself." do they? We need no memory for storing pthread_rwlock_t; but there is lll_futex_wait with futex syscall in rwlock methods like http://osxr.org:8080/glibc/source/nptl/pthread_rwlock_rdlock.c#0030. Is it true that futex don't require any resources when there is waiter or waiters? Waiters should be saved in-kernel in some list or other data structure.

Comment: @osgx: That's not a per-lock resource, that's a per-waiter resource.

Comment: Thank you. For this particular application I will almost certainly never need anything other than modern Linux but it's useful to know that there is at least the _potential_ for it requiring resources that can be exhausted,. I can insert lots of comments to that effect in the code should it ever need to be ported elsewhere.